# How to clone a repository with longer paths using LibGit2Sharp library?

Tags: git, wiki, libgit2sharp

I am writing a Azure function to pull data from a repository and store it in a folder. My repo has long file names. I am getting the following error `LibGit2Sharp: path too long:`. How can I resolve this?

The library has next to none documentation.